You take a walk, man
This is really bugging me. I'm trying to remember what movie or tv show this scene is from. Its obviously from the 80's or 90s. 
There are at least two characters. We'll call them Joe and Bob for the sake of presentation. In the scene Joe is asking Bob what this device is and its a walkman. The dialogue goes essentially like this. 

Joe: What do you call this thing?
Bob: Oh that's a... walkman
Joe: You take a walk man, I asked you what this is called? 


sounds like a bad "Back to the Future" joke

That was the first thing I checked. Its not.

Here's a close one from City Guys, a sitcom that ran on NBC in the late 90s, in a scene where L-Train (Steven Daniel) plays an old man being interviewed on TV, claiming that he came up with the name:

Host: You were witness to one of the great moments in electronics history: The creation of the Walkman.
L-Train: Walkman, yeah, that's right. I was hanging out with my friend Sony one day, and he showed me this portable stereo. See, he didn't know what to call it. So I said, "Why don't you think about it while you take a walk, man?"

You can see the scene here around 4:56:




Wow, great answer but unfortunately not the one I'm thinking of.
